# How to import an aws_spot_instance_request into Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-ec2

I'm looking for a way to import an `aws_spot_instance_request` into Terraform.

I already made a Spot Request on AWS console, now I would like to put this request on my code. How can I do that?

In the [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/spot_instance_request) there is no mention how to import it, but there is instructions on how to do it for [aws_spot_fleet_request](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/spot_fleet_request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there is really no way to do it for now.